# Linux kernel IPv4 and IPv6 socket creation: EPROTONOSUPPORT and ESOCKTNOSUPPORT errors

Tags: sockets, linux-kernel, ipv6, network-protocols, ipv4

I'm trying to understand [IPv4 socket](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.1/source/net/ipv4/af_inet.c) and [IPv6 socket](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.1/source/net/ipv6/af_inet6.c) Linux kernel implementations.

Both methods
[`inet_create()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.1/source/net/ipv4/af_inet.c#L246)
and
[`inet6_create()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.1/source/net/ipv6/af_inet6.c#L110)
looks very similar.
They both can return to user space `EPROTONOSUPPORT` or `ESOCKTNOSUPPORT`, I wonder on which circumstances this can happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ESOCKTNOSUPPORT`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html) means that the socket type is not supported for the chosen protocol. For instance, you can't create a `SOCK_SEQPACKET` with `IPPROTO_IP`. According to the [ip(7) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html), only `SOCK_STREAM`, `SOCK_DGRAM` and `SOCK_RAW` are valid socket types for ip.

[`EPROTONOSUPPORT`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) means that the socket protocol chosen is not supported. For instance, if you ask for `AF_INET6` and the system administrator has disabled IPv6 by blacklisting the module.

Comment: According to [socket(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) blacklisted IPv6 module cause `EAFNOSUPPORT` (no `EPROTONOSUPPORT`). But I probably don't understand the meaning, as kernel commit [net: ping: Return EAFNOSUPPORT when appropriate](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?h=6d0bfe226116&id=9145736d4862145684009d6a72a6e61324a9439e) describe different usage for `EAFNOSUPPORT`.